# how to use SoapClient in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, xml-namespaces, soap-client

ask about yii2 use SoapClient questions, thanks.
This is a java webservice, address: `http://122.114.18.101/MyWebServicesPort?wsdl`
I want to call `validateFalseInfo` method server.
This is the actual string by server requires me to submit the

```
PFJFUVVFU1Q + PFVTRVI + Q0cyMDAwMDAxPC9VU0VSPjxQQVNTV09SRD5mNmFhNTY4NDNhOTRjNWFlNjBkNjMxNzVkZTZlZTQ4MTY3MDcxOWZlMmU2MjdiYTZjM2RmNTA5ZDkxOWZjNDI5PC9QQVNTV09SRD48Q09ORElUSU9OPjxTSlJYTT48L1NKUlhNPjxaSkhNPjIxMDEwNDE5ODUwNjAyMDA5eDwvWkpITT48L0NPTkRJVElPTj48L1JFUVVFU1Q +
```

The problem is: I am using c # call the method, the same submission get is

```
 PFJFU1VMVD48REFUQS8 + PFNUQVRFPjEwMTwvU1RBVEU + PC9SRVNVTFQ +
```

after base64 decryption

```
<RESULT><DATA/><STATE>101</STATE></RESULT>
```

But when I use php SoapClient or use https://github.com/mongosoft/yii2-soap-client in yii2. Return Values ​​decrypt all

```
<RESULT><DATA/><STATE>301</STATE></RESULT>
```

I do not know why the 301 results obtained by the same content php.
Information returned from the server

> 101 = success, 301 = Abnormal

Here are some network information

php5.5.11 SoapClient network information

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.com/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:validateFalseInfo/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

c# SoapClient network information

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<validateFalseInfo xmlns="http://webservice.com/">
<arg0 xmlns="">PFJFUVVFU1Q+PFVTRVI+Q0cyMDAwMDAxPC9VU0VSPjxQQVNTV09SRD5mNmFhNTY4NDNhOTRjNWFlNjBkNjMxNzVkZTZlZTQ4MTY3MDcxOWZlMmU2MjdiYTZjM2RmNTA5ZDkxOWZjNDI5PC9QQVNTV09SRD48Q09ORElUSU9OPjxTSlJYTT48L1NKUlhNPjxaSkhNPjIxMDEwNDE5ODUwNjAyMDA5eDwvWkpITT48L0NPTkRJVElPTj48L1JFUVVFU1Q+</arg0>
</validateFalseInfo>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Hoping to get help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you call the *validateFalseInfo* method without any arguments. You should add your PHP code with the call to the question.

Comment: thanks, my bed,  that method   need  'arg0' parameter